# How to count similar domains in emails and print every domain only once[python]?

Tags: python, printing, output

I have dataset of 10 hotmail emails, 4 gmails, 3 mail.com. I want to analyze list of emails and print how many of each domain(hotmail,gmail etc) is there and print out. But i do it in a very bruteforce way.
I know python has elegant short code(e.g. itertools, islice, xrange)

hotmail:   10
gmail:     4
mail.com:  3

but i get this:

hotmail
10
hotmail
10
...
hotmail
10
gmail
4
gmail
4
gmail
4
gmail
4
etc

```
def count_domains( emails):

    for email in emails:

        current_email = email.split("@", 2)[1] # splits at @, john@mail.com => mail.com, 
                                               #2nd index in the list
        print(current_email)
        current_domain_counter = 0
        for email2 in emails:
            if current_email == email2.split("@",2)[1]:
                current_domain_counter = current_domain_counter + 1
        #print(current_email current_domain_counter)
        print(current_domain_counter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put all strings into a list, say myList, you can make it unique using

```
uniqueList = list(set(myList))
```

Afterwards, you can can count the occurrences using, e.g. to get the count of the first string

```
countFirst = myList.count(uniqueList[0])
```

You can put things together, like

```
[[domain,myList.count(domain)] for domain in set(myList)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use collections.Counter:

```
email=['me@mail.com','you@mail.com',"me@gmail.com","you@gmail.com","them@gmail.com",'you@hotmail.com',"me@hotmail.com","you@hotmail.com","them@hotmail.com"]


from collections import Counter 
def count_domains(emails):
    c = Counter()
    for email in emails:
        current_email = email.split("@", 2)[1] # splits at @, john@mail.com => mail.com, 
        c.update([current_email]) # wrap in list or will end up counting each letter                                     #2nd index in the list
    print(c.most_common()) # print most common domains
    print ("gmail.com count = {}".format(c["gmail.com"]))
    print ("mail.com count = {}".format(c["mail.com"]))
    print ("hotmail.com count = {}".format(c["hotmail.com"]))

print count_domains(email)

[('hotmail.com', 4), ('gmail.com', 3), ('mail.com', 2)]
gmail.com count = 3
mail.com count = 2
hotmail.com count = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doing too much (at least I think so).  Splitting the strings is unnecessary.  You can just check the entire string for the "@gmail.com", "@hotmail.com", "@mail.com", etc keywords and add each to its own counter.

```
gmail_counter = 0
hotmail_counter = 0
mail_counter = 0
# Add as many counters as required
for email in emails:
    if email.find("@gmail.com") >= 0
        gmail_counter += 1
    elif email.find("@hotmail.com") >= 0
        hotmail_counter += 1
    elif email.find("@mail.com") >= 0
        mail_counter += 1
    # ...
```